# try function failing to check message and emoji using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm attempting to construct a react command that just reacts to a stated message using ID, with the emoji stated after the message, but the problem is that it fails to verify whether the message is valid, and I can't get it to check if the emoji is valid as well. Is there any way around this?

The code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'react',
    category: 'Staff',
    aliases: [],
    description: 'Reacts to a message.',
    usage: 'react <messageID> <emoji>',
    userperms: [],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let emoji = args[1];
    let messageID = args[0];

    if (!messageID) return message.reply('Please state the messageID!')
    if (!emoji) return message.reply('Please state the emoji')

    if (messageID && emoji) {
      /*try { 
        message.channel.messages.fetch(messageID).then(m => m.react(emoji));
        message.channel.send('Reacted!')
      } catch {
        message.channel.send('This message is not valid or it isn\'t in the same channel!')
      }*/
    try {
      console.log('s')
      await Promise.all([message.channel.messages.fetch(_messageID)])
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code == 10008) {
            message.channel.send('Failed to find the message!');
            return
        }
      }
      try {
        message.channel.messages.fetch(_messageID).react(emoji)
      } catch (error) {
        message.channel.send('Please use a valid emoji!')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems work for me. Have you make sure you copy the correct Message ID? If it returns like `926542311683399790-928970526125330472` then just remove the first number in front. And instead use the last one (`928970526125330472`).

Comment: My problem is, it doesn't check if it's a real message or not and if the emoji exists

Comment: Ah sorry for the misunderstanding. So did you mean it doesn't send the 'Failed to find the message!' things when its not a valid message?

Comment: Yes, and same with emoji

Comment: Ah okay, let me try to answer those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I try your code in my bot. And yes it doesn't work with the try function. What you can do is to catch the code instantly when it have the error.

Here is the example (with a little bit improvement. You can remove some)

```
if (messageID && emoji) {

  // your commented code

  message.channel.messages.fetch(messageID)
  .catch(err => {

    // The message is not found.
    if (err.code === 10008){
        message.channel.send('Failed to find the message!');
        return;
    }

    // The ID that entered is not a Message ID (Basically not a number)
    if (err.code === 50035){
        message.channel.send('You enter a Invalid type of Message ID!');
        return;
    }
  });
}
```

**Edit** : For the emoji one. It will return `<pending>` because it try to react message that still not fetched yet. Sorry, my bad. This should work as I have try it now :

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(messageID)
.then(msg => {
    msg.react(emoji)
    .catch(err => {
        message.channel.send('Please use a valid emoji!');
        return;         
    }
});
```

I don't know exactly why this happen. I think it because the code already break before the catch function called (?)

`Promise.all` and `await` will also works.

```
await Promise.all([message.channel.messages.fetch(messageID)]).catch(...)
```

Tell me if its works or not now.

Comment: The message checker works, but the emoji one no. (even if it's valid)

Comment: The error:  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.messages.fetch(...).react is not a function

Comment: I have edit it, try the new one. It works for me.